# NSURLRequest in UIWebview: Does it store PDFs to the iPhone device once it makes the request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, nsurlrequest

I have implemented an NSURLRequest in a UIWebView and it's grabbing a link to a .pdf on the network.

My question is -- is it storing the PDF on the iOS device -- meaning the following day - does the application make a new request to retrieve the PDF or is grabbing the saved PDF on the iPhone?

The reason I'm asking is because:
I was doing some error checking and noticed that when my iPhone was in airplane mode - it would still get the PDF. The only way it didn't get the PDF and displayed the error that I expected was if I deleted the application and retried to get the PDF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An `NSURLRequest` doesn't store anything. If you want anything to happen you need to use it with an `NSURLConnection` and you need to handle the data as needed as it comes in through the delegate methods. Show some relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy Maybe I didn't ask the question correctly. In my viewDidLoad method, I'm making an NSURLRequest and loading that request into my web view. Everything works great. It gets the PDF; I'm able to zoom in, etc. I decided to add in some error checking (just in case the user didn't have internet access). When I did this, I put my iPhone in "airplane" mode. I tested it out and I didn't get the error. My application was still getting the PDF... which made me wonder, is the application somehow storing a PDF since the URL is going directly to a .pdf link. I'm not saving the data in my code.

Comment: You didn't mention your use a web view in your question. The file is probably being cached. Enter airplane mode and try to access a URL you haven't accessed before.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I'm sorry. I didn't realize I didn't put that in there. I didn't think about the cache! I did do a test by deleting the entire app & re-trying to access the web view and I got the error I expected. It's probably the cache. I'm guessing I would have to clear the cache when the view loads to enforce it to grab the pdf every time?

Comment: @rmaddy In the dealloc method, I added this `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` and it fixed it. Thank you so much for your help! I'll edit my question so that it mentions the web view. =)